# Django Channels: Get stuck after period of time

Tags: django, django-channels

I run code from https://github.com/andrewgodwin/channels-examples/tree/master/multichat for around 50 users.

It goes to get stuck without any notice. Server is not down, access log has nothing special. When I stop daphne server (with Ctrl+C), it takes about 5-10 minutes to completely go down. Sometime I have to run kill command.

It is very weird when I put daphne inside supervisord, I restart it every 30 minutes using crontab, websocket can be connected normally. It's hacky but working.

My config: HAProxy => Daphne

`daphne -b 192.168.0.6 -p 8000 yyapp.asgi:application --access-log=/home/admin/daphne.log`

```
backend daphne
        balance source
        option http-server-close
        option forceclose
        timeout check 1000ms
        reqrep ^([^\ ]*)\ /ws/(.*) \1\ /\2
        server daphne 192.168.0.6:8000 check maxconn 10000 inter 5s
```

Debian: 9.4 (original kernel) on OVH server.
Python: 3.6.4
Daphne: 2.2.1
Channels: 2.1.2
Django: 1.11.15
Redis: 4.0.11

[image]

[image]

I know this question may be too general, but I really have no ideas with this. I tried upgrade python, re-install all the packages but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you ever come to a resolution?

Comment: @kunambi I'm currently still using a hacky method that restart daphne service each 30 minutes (by crontab). Users can feel a little bit inconvenience but It's working and  I have no time to invest in this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Well, web servers and load balancers are, in general, very bad with persistent connections. You need to give Haproxy explicit instructions so it knows when and how to timeout unused tunnels.

There are four timeouts that Haproxy will need to keep track of:

1. timeout client
2. timeout connect
3. timeout server
4. timeout tunnel

The first three are related to the initial HTTP negotiation phase of the socket connection. As soon as the connection is established, only timeout tunnel matters. You will need to tinker with the values for your own application, but some suggested values to start with are:

1. timeout client: 25s
2. timeout connect: 5s
3. timeout server: 25s
4. timeout tunnel: 3600s

In your code, that would be:

```
backend daphne
    balance source
    option http-server-close
    option forceclose
    timeout check 1000ms
    timeout client 25s
    timeout connect 5s
    timeout server 25s
    timeout tunnel 3600s
    reqrep ^([^\ ]*)\ /ws/(.*) \1\ /\2
    server daphne 192.168.0.6:8000 check maxconn 10000 inter 5s
```

You might need to tinker with the other timeouts to get a good mixture. Some timeouts that may affect your setup - and some starting values - are:

1. timeout http-keep-alive: 1s
2. timeout http-request: 15s
3. timeout queue: 30s
4. timeout tarpit: 60s

Of course, read up and customize to suit your needs.

Reference:
[Haproxy - Websockets Load Balancing](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/websockets-load-balancing-with-haproxy/)